# Are speculative questions allowed, such as what Marx would think about something that hadn't happened yet?

Tags: discussion

Are speculative questions allowed, such as what Marx would think about something that hadn't happened yet?

[What do Marxists make of contemporary technophobia?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/65379/what-do-marxists-make-of-contemporary-technophobia)